# Cómo llamar una arrow function desde otra funcion que escucha un evento de KeyPress en REACT

Tags: html, reactjs, funciones, redux, jsx

```
class x extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
           this.segundaFuncion = this.segundaFuncion.bind(this);
             this.primeraFuncion= this.primeraFuncion.bind(this);
             }`




    primeraFuncion= (event) => {
        if(event.key === 'Enter'){
          this.segundaFuncion("item")
        }
      }



    segundaFuncion = field => () => {
```

//llamado a una acción con Redux

```
    }


            Item() {
        return (
          <div>
            <TextField         
              onChange={this.handleChange} 
              onKeyPress={this.primeraFuncion}        
            />
            <IconButton      
              onClick={this.SegundaFuncion("item")}        

            >
              <AddIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        );
      }`



    render() {    
        return (
          <div>
            <this.Item/>
    )
```

Estoy intentando activar el método de la arrow function después de un evento de Enter.Cuando hago uso de la funcion desde el componente, SI funciona, pero cuando la intento ejectutar desde el metodo "primera funcion" la cual es una funcion que evalua un ENTER. no funciona.

Comment: ¿No funciona en que sentido?

Comment: Disculpa creo que redacte super mal mi primera pregunta en Stack, no funciona en el sentido, de que no logro hacer que realize la "segunda funcion" como si fuera el evento de Click del componente. puse un Debugger para ver si llega a la función, pero no, no lo hace.

Comment: Creo que tiene que ver con que la tienes definida como `segundaFuncion = field => () => {`, cuando debería ser `segundaFuncion = (field) => {`. Si no, revisa el código que veo algunos errores en tu código, como `this.segundaFuncion .bind(this)` (hay un espacio) o ciertos carácteres ` que tienes en tu código.

Comment: Recuerda pasar la función sin los paréntesis, prueba eso, ahí la estas ejecutando

Comment: cuando realizo lo que comentas,(Quitar los parentesis) se ejecuta de inmediato la función, al momento de Renderear :( he estado leyendo y es algo del tema del contexto, pero sigo buscando en donde esta mi error. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

en esta parte de tu codigo estas llamando bien la `primeraFuncion`

```
    <TextField         
      onChange={this.handleChange} 
      onKeyPress={this.primeraFuncion}        
    />
```

Pero en la segunda function la tienes definida como una function que retorna otra funcion

```
segundaFuncion = field => () => {
```

Tendrias que definirla asi:

```
segundaFuncion = field => {
```

En esta otra parte de tu codigo, no se si fue a prosito pero el nombre de la funcion esta en mayuscula, tendria que ser en miniscula

```
    <IconButton      
      onClick={this.SegundaFuncion("item")}        

    >
```

pero si llamas la funcion dentro del onClick se ejecutara cuando se renderice el componente. Tendrias que hacerlo asi, una funcion que retorna o ejecuta tu `segundaFuncion` y le pasas un parametro.

```
    <IconButton      
      onClick={() => this.SegundaFuncion("item")}
```

Otra cosa, no necesitas hacer el `.bind` ya que tus metodos/funciones los defines con un arrow function.
        >

Comment: Muchisimaaaaaaaaas gracias Isaac, funciono!!